# What size should images in eBooks be?

Tags: ebook, artwork

I'm creating an ebook that has images in it. What size / resolution should images in an ebook be?

Comment: What format? ...

Comment: kindle and pngs / jpegs

Comment: checked Amazon's docs?

Comment: What I've read is that you should be careful with the file size. so probably max 1600 x 1400

Comment: Max file size 5Mb according to https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A1B6GKJ79HC7AN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the deal with Kindle images. The bigger, the better -- up to the max size (in bytes 5Mb) The largest Height x Width possible so users can zoom in.  Why do I say this?  Because the **Kindle Reader now allows the reader to click the image and then zoom in on it**.

That means you want the image to have a high resolution so the user can click on the image inline (in the text) and the Kindle Reader will take over and allow the user to zoom in using multitouch features of pads (iPad, iPhone, Android, etc).

So, the better the resolution the better the experience.  I know this is true because I've tested it in my own books where I've used graphics and I've also been pleased and annoyed by other author's books I've bought which had good or bad resolutions set and then I couldn't really see their images clearly.

Comment: 'dpi' means 'dots per inch'. This refers to paper when the image is printed. For an (pixel) image viewed on a digital device it is meaningless. What isn't meaningless is the size of the image (height x width).

Comment: @Smithers - you are right.  I was thinking when zoomed that dpi would matter, but at that point it is only the image size that matters on screen.  I altered the answer.